# How to create the iOS 8 Dialog with black background color and white text ?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am working on customizing the dialog (UIAlertView) to make it from white to black ,

[Dark Dialog , no need red baR](http://omahpsd.com/psd-design/free-ios-alert-dialog/)
suiting the theme if UI design. After setting the dialog in black colour, there are still white background colour , black text and blue text for buttons Would you please tell me the workout ? The below is my working:

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                                message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", _labels[87],@". " ,  _labels[88] , @"?"]
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:_labels[89] otherButtonTitles: _labels[0], nil  ];

                [alert setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor] ];

                alert.alpha = 0.8f;
                alert.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

                alert.tag = 15;
                [alert show];
```

Comment: 1. UIAlertView is deprecated, use UIAlertController. 2. It looks like that image you posted is a custom UIView, not anything native.

Comment: can UIAlertController be used for iOS 6 and 7  ? What if I am going to create 1 ) an input text dialog and  2) dialog with number picker and  image ?